# 'Building workspace' has encountered an error

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, workspace

Eclipse Luna 4.4.0

Error occurred during the Build

```java
Error instantiating builder 'ord.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder'.
Plug-in org.eclipse.m2e.core was unable to load class org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core (547).
Plug-in org.eclipse.m2e.core was unable to load class org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core (547).
Error instantiating builder 'org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder'.
Plug-in org.eclipse.m2e.core was unable to load class org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.m23.core (547).
Plug-in org.eclipse.m2e.core was unable to load class org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.
an error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core (547).
```

if i delete the folder `.metadata` and all `.project` and `.setting` data from my workspace, i get no error. After one day of work i´ll get the same error.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try next steps:

1. Go to your eclipse installation folder
2. Run "eclipse.exe -clean"
3. Work normally
4. Enjoy

Comment: I had changed jdk version in eclipse.ini. clean launch fixed the issue.

Comment: This also worked for me too. Thanks!!! PS: I got this error after updating m2e plugin in. There was another eclipse instance running during the update. I think this was the problem...

Comment: Running -clean worked for me. On Mac this command is '/Applications/eclipse\ 3/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse -clean'

Comment: -clean helped Luna 4.4.1

Comment: Also helped on Mars

Comment: Worked for Neon.1

Comment: I am using Neon 1, but i got this issue only on 1 project from github the error is: `Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'ProjectName'.
Could not initialize class com.android.tools.lint.checks.BuiltinIssueRegistry`

Comment: Didn't work for me, instead I changed the -vm argument in eclipse.ini and it did the trick

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this same issue and I believe the culprit to be the Sonarqube plugin I had installed.

This discussion pointed me in that direction:

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/749864-sts-ggts-3-6-0-m1-released

Uninstalled the Sonarqube plugin and the error is gone.

Comment: Same issue.  Installing the SonarQube plugin brought eclipse to its knees.  Will file bug report with SQ soon.

Answer (score 3):

I uninstalled my Netbeans because Eclipse and Netbeans are both usin the same workspace.

i uninstalled Netbeans and the error is gone.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem resulted to be my Eclipse was running on an outdated IBM Java Virtual Machine. I updated my IBM JRE, I modified my eclipse.ini in order to update the -vm parameter so it points to the new installation, and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case none of the above solutions worked. I used eclipse with two different workspaces, one works, seconds had this error. My solution was it to copy from the working workspace the following files over the corrupted one:

```
[workspace]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core
[workspace]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui
[workspace]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.jdt
[workspace]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.launching
[workspace]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration
```

I'm using eclipse mars 64-bit version.
So maybe before your whole workspace gets broken this might be a solution from a clean installation to copy.

Answer (score 1):

I keep my Workspace on Dropbox. I had this issue occur, and managed to solve it by searching within [workspace]/.metadata/ for the word 'conflicted' and deleting all these files Dropbox had created. Error was gone when I restarted Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

exclude the error js files. it will definitely will work..

Answer (score 0):

I have added 'javaw.exe' in the bin file (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-X.X.X\bin) as a System variable and deleted all the module info. This worked for me. However, this might be specific to the Enterprise Java package.